# mysqli not talking to php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Working on a brand new, virtual server, based on Ubuntu.

I'm installing Moodle (no help on those pages) over SSH. During the installation procedure, I was prompted to install cURL. I did that but got an error. I found a better command that ran without the error. When Apache2 restarted, my installation status page (where the curl notice was placed) was broken and a static "database driver error detected" page shows up saying that mysqli and php aren't communicating. When I view phpinfo, I don't see mysql nor mysqli listed in the loaded modules. The mysqli.ini file IS being parsed but it's not loading.

In the terminal, MySQL is operating normally. I can log in and do anything I want. The webserver is operating normally except for this error.

I even upgraded to the newest version of Ubuntu (12.x) and the error persists, even though I used the package maintainer's .ini file.

I'd appreciate any thoughts about how to restore the mysqli functionality in my web server.

Comment: could you post the contents of your mysqli.ini file please?

Comment: ; configuration for php MySQL module
extension=mysqli.so

Comment: That's all of it: the commented line, the extension line...

Comment: that's all it should need, try restarting Apache (or nginx or whatever you use) - just to make sure though, that is 2 lines in that file (stackoverflow is making it look like 1)

Comment: It is two lines; thanks. Yeah, the restart doesn't solve the problem. Mysqli doesn't appear in phpinfo. CLI works fine, so the mysql process is running.